# Bamboo stop ongoing build when a new one is scheduled

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bamboo

If there are multiple pushes to branch, Bamboo schedules separated builds for every push which creates redundancy on the queue. We only care about the last build with the latest changes for ours pull requests. Therefore, is there any way/configuration to cancel ongoing/scheduled builds if new build is scheduled?

I figured out `Enable quiet period` option (Quiet period allows you to delay building after a single commit is detected, aggregating multiple commits per build). However, quiet period is not the best way to handle the redundancy on the queue.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: IMHO that's not redundancy, https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/10322/47.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. It is somewhat of an anti-pattern to avoid building each time code is committed.  If you cancel an ongoing build, you could theoretically go all day without ever knowing if a commit at the beginning of the day broke the build if incoming commits keep cancelling the build.  Taking this approach you would lose the benefits of having a continuous integration system.
2. If you only care about the builds going into your mainline branch then you can edit how branches are built by going to `Plan Configuration -> Branches`.  You can select Manually or "When pull request is created".  The latter will only trigger a branch build when the PR is created and is updated.
3. You can further limit what is running by using the [Conditional tasks for Bamboo plugin.](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219706/conditional-tasks-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview)  While not as clean as not starting a build, you could choose to only execute time consuming tasks when your main branch is building, which would allow for faster execution on branches.

Finally, you could theoretically use the [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/using-the-bamboo-rest-apis/) to create your own custom plugin/application that stops builds.